# BICEP - Parameter file variable assignment

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I was following the repo for separate parameter file to each env as defined in the https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/4586

I tried the separate parameters file for dev, stage, prod but the value assignment in main module variable remains flagged by intelligence even though it exists same param exist in the respective parameter file.

Other approach I tried is loadjson variable, but it does not show auto completion for items under subnet block as it stopes right after value.

Maybe I am overthinking and not applying the correct approach, Perhaps I should ignore intellisense and try deploying by applying parameter and hope it will auto pick correct value during the deployment param check.

Here is my parameter file and the same value applies to each env param json.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "department": {
      "value": "finance"
    },
    "saAccountCount": {
      "value": 1
    },
    "vmCount": {
      "value": 1
    },
    "locationIndex": { //idenx 1 = app server, 2=AD, 3=Tool server, 4= dchp server
      "value": 1
    },
    "appRoleIndex": { //idenx 1 = westus2, 2= westus, 3= eastus, 4=centralus, 5=uswest3
      "value": 1
    },

    "appRole": {
      "value": {
        "Applicatoin Server": "ap",
        "Active Directory": "dc",
        "Tool server": "tool",
        "DHCP server": "dhcp"
      }
    },
    "environment": {
      "value": "dev"
    },
    "addressPrefixes": {
      "value": [
        "172.16.0.0/20"
      ]
    },
    "dnsServers": {
      "value": [
        "1.1.1.1",
        "4.4.4.4"
      ]
    },
    "locationList": {
      "value": {
        "westus2": "azw2",
        "westus": "azw",
        "Eastus": "aze",
        "CentralUS": "azc",
        "westus3": "azw3"
      }
    },
    "subnets": {
      "value": [
        {
          "name": "frontend",
          "subnetPrefix": "172.16.2.0/24",
          "delegation": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
          "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "disabled",
          "serviceEndpoints": [
            {
              "service": "Microsoft.KeyVault",
              "locations": [
                "*"
              ]
            },
            {
              "service": "Microsoft.Web",
              "locations": [
                "*"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "backend",
          "subnetPrefix": "172.16.3.0/24",
          "delegation": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
          "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "enabled",
          "serviceEndpoints": [
            {
              "service": "Microsoft.KeyVault",
              "locations": [
                "*"
              ]
            },
            {
              "service": "Microsoft.Web",
              "locations": [
                "*"
              ]
            },
            {
              "service": "Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB",
              "locations": [
                "*"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the exact issue is you are facing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You appear to be attempting to deploy an Azure Resource Management (ARM) template using a parameter file.
- The parameter file is used to pass values to the ARM template during deployment. The parameter file must use the same types as the ARM template and can only include values for the ARM template's parameters.

***You will receive an error if the parameter file contains extra parameters that do not match the ARM template's parameters.***

*In the same deployment process, you can use both inline parameters and a local parameter file. If you specify a parameter's value in both the local parameter file and inline, the inline value takes priority.*

[Refer to create a parameter file of an ARM template](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/templates/parameter-files.md)

About the different parameters file for `dev, stage, and prod`, it's likely that the parameter file is not correctly linked to the ARM template.

- You can deploy the ARM template with the parameter file to determine if it will automatically select the proper value during the deployment parameter check.
- Regarding the loadjson variable, it is possible that the loadjson variable is not properly formatted.

***You can double-check the loadjson variable's format to ensure it's proper.***

After a workaround on this, I created a sample `parameter.json` file for a webapp to deploy in a `production` environment and that worked for me.

[image]

**Note:** Alternatively, You can use [az deployment group create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/deployment/group?view=azure-cli-latest) with a parameters file and deploy into Azure to avoid these conflicts.

Comment: Yes, the value of the environment variable was out of range which was causing the issue. I was focusing more the location index and it turned out to be env. Thanks for your response and sorry about the late comment, I did not check your screen shot on time. But you are correct about the environment